# How to use _LINE_ in PHP to display current line of execution

Tags: php

I am studying PHP and in my book one line given that is :

> "using echo *_LINE_* at a specific location in a script will display the
>   current line that's executing"

I tried the code  `echo _LINE_;` but this will gives me Notice

Here is NOTICE :

> Notice: Use of undefined constant *LINE* - assumed '*LINE*' in C:\wamp\www\New\index.php on line 17

I don't understand how this work please anyone suggest...

Comment: Why does the error message say `LINE` when the code says `_LINE_`? Are you sure you copied them both correctly?

Comment: Those are called "magic constans" - I guess its nice to know in the beginning.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to use :

```
echo __LINE__;
```

with two underscores.

Comment: Look http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b3b6bbb3ba49a4edfc767d8782f7a28392b8e0e7, it's work. What's your php version ?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you need to use:

```
<?php

echo __LINE__;

?>
```

NOTE:Double underscore not single underscore.

Comment: Oh that was my mistake actually it prints value but it mixes in another one so I did not recognize the line number... echo pi; 
    echo *__LINE__*;
    echo PI;